# Texture runs completely off the mesh and looks different to material preview

Tags: texturing, uv

I downloaded a simple wood texture and am trying to apply it to this bowling lane. I got node wrangle to set up the nodes for me, and then did a UV wrap projected from top view. In material preview it looks completely fine, but for some reason rendered view makes it looks atrocious
[image: Material Preview]

[image: Rendered view]

[image: UV wrap]

I did admittedly do some meddling with the mesh earlier in the setup. I had the lane you see there split into two pieces then re-joined. I don't know if this would affect it though, and I had no idea the texture could run off the mesh or look different to material preview

https://www.cgbookcase.com/textures/parquet-flooring-07/

Any help is greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: @moonboots That should read **pack** your images! File > External Data > Pack Resources. :^)

Comment: oops sorry yes, could you please pack your image and share your file: blend-exchange.com

Comment: @Confused_User A texture cannot show up in "empty space" without a mesh. It just looks like that in _Rendered_ view because the outline of the selected object shows the object as it is without some modifier that becomes visible in render and produces this outstretched version of the object. There is a modifier on the "Lane" object, which one is it? You're not showing that in the screenshot.

Comment: If I see the material correctly, you have some displacement there. This for example is something that changes the geometry in rendered view but shows the outline of the unchanged geometry.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann There was an array modifier on the lane but even when I remove it the texture runs off the mesh. It also has a rigid body simulation passive on it, but that shouldn't change anything

Comment: @moonboots oops, yep, sorry, uploaded the file now. I forgot to pack the image so I'll just provide a link to the textures

Comment: It doesn't look like you've shared the good file, there are just 2 planes that don't have any material

Comment: @moonboots It is there, but it's in a different scene sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a *Displacement* node, it displaces the topology and can only be seen in *Renedered* preview, unplug it, or in the *Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement*, choose *Bump Only*, or if you want it to work properly, apply the scale and subdivide your object :

[image]